# Polar set. Continuous dual space of $c_0$.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I need to find a Polar set in dual space for the following subset of $c_0$.
Let $X = c_0$ ($c_0$ — Banach space of sequences converging to zero). We have a set: $A_1 = \{x \in c_0: x_1+x_2>-2\}$ ($x_1$ and $x_2$ — coordinates of vector $x$).

My attempt:
Dual space of $c_0$ is $l_1$.

As I know Polar set of subset of $c_0$ in dual space: $A_1' = \{y \in l_1: \sup(|(x,y)|) < 1\}$(sup here for all x from $A_1$). So in general case we got a module of a complex number : $|x_1y_1+x_2y_2|$ and we need other $y_i = 0$ for all $i = 3,4,5,...$, because we have no limitation for other $x_i$. Now we may assume that polar set contains vector such as $(y_1, y_2, 0, 0, ...)$. Is there any way to find all of this $y_1, y_2$?(other than pick). Also is this logic right?

Answer (score 1):

Logically right. But if you have $sup$ => [so it means exact upper bound] => you have no limitation for $x_1$ and $x_2$ => Polar set it's only one vector: $(0,0,0,0,...)$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).